# Jolt transformation to add a attribute to a JSON object

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have two JSON objects as input and want to add a value of one object to the other.
I have tried many different specs, but I can't get it to work.

Here is an example of the situation:

Input:

```
{
  "all": {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2",
    "c": "3"
  },
  "partially": {
    "d": "4",
    "e": "5",
    "f": "6"
  }
}
```

I want to have all data from the "all" object and I do not know what keys will be present. 
On the other hand I know the keys of the "partially" object and I want to shift only selected.
So for example here is a desired output:

```
{
  "result" : {
    "a" : "1",
    "b" : "2",
    "c" : "3",
    "d" : "4"
  }
}
```

This is my current spec, but it produces an array with separate data and does not select only "d" from the "partially". If I try to select only "d" it shifts the value but not the key, but I need both:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "all": "result",
      "partially": "result"
    }
  }
]
```

Is there any way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "all": {
        "@": "result",
        "@(1,partially.d)": "result.d"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is not very important, but is it possible to sort the output of "result" the other way around? So that "d" would be the first entry in "result" as so: "d", "a", "b", "c"?